# nvarchar(max) causing errors

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am trying to load data from an Oracle source into a SQL Server database. One of the columns being loaded is a result of concatenation. There are a lot of values which are 6000 or 7000 characters long. The destination table has been set up as `nvarchar(max)` so that we don't encounter any issues with truncation.

However, when the SSIS package runs, it still fails saying that the result string is too long. I have gone into the advanced editor in SSIS and explicitly changed it to be a `DT_NTEXT unicode textstream`. It still fails.

Please help.

If there is no other way, I will just truncate the values to 4000 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue in the past. Unfortunately it can not be solved due to internal implementation limit of the drivers or SSIS. Basically the limit is 8000 characters on Oracle side, it corresponds to 4000 Unicode characters. Conversion to unicode happens somewhere on the Oracle -> SQL Server path and can not be avoided. Even if the declaration is simple varchar on both sides.

Comment: how can i truncate the strings then in the ssis package. is there way

Comment: Easiest way would be to use a `substr` function on the corresponding columns in your `SELECT` in the data source.

Answer (score 1):

If @Milan.Švec is correct, then you just need to think outside the box.

- you know SSIS is finicky
- Oracle may not have the right driver
- a simple text/csv file can be read in (DT_NTEXT)

1) Push from Oracle the data onto a csv file.

2) Make sure to define your delimiters so that double-quotations are accounted for.

- *It is crucial you account for the correct delimiter*
- **Use the delimiter to make sure your data is correctly inside each column**. Heavens knows how frustrating dirty data can be when columns are incorrectly pushed to the wrong row/column.

3) from your SSIS package, read from said csv file onto a staging table if needed.

- Otherwise, push to final table and skip step 4.

4) run Transformation operations to guarantee your data and Load into the final table.

There are a few other ways you can do this, of course, but csv is universal and at least is straightforward. Avoid EXCEL files as they tend to be very buggy in some versions.

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a answer. 
its the CLOB function in oracle. If i dont define any XMLElements, i can bypass the 4000 character limitation through the SSIS.

http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/datatypes/clob